# How to send the data CLOB AND BLOB types to the database from java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, blob, clob

I need insert some clob and blob types of data to my database using java. But do this task by using following code it show

```
           import java.io.*;
           import java.sql.*;
           import java.util.*;
           public class InsertusrProf
           {
    public static Connection prepareConnection()throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
    String dcn="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@JamesPJ-PC:1521:skprk";
    String usname="system";
    String pass="Theking123";
    Class.forName(dcn);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url,usname,pass);
}
public static void InsTable(String uname,Blob photo1,Blob video1,Blob music1,Clob notes1,Clob messages1,String link,String frd,Clob cmt,String lik,String ulik,Blob shrs,Clob qst,Clob answ,Blob updt,String thms,Clob wrd,String langs,String rlgn,String prvc,String hbs,String fvt,String qlf,String comm,String grp,String pgs,Clob ntfcn,String rqst,Clob tps,String cty,String tg)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(1024);;
    sb.append("insert into ").append(uname).append("(PHOTO,VIDEO,MUSIC,NOTES,MESSAGES,LINKS,FRIENDS,COMMENTS,LIKES,UNLIKES,SHARES,QSTNS,ANS,UPDATES,THEMS,WORDS,LANGUAGES,RELEGION,PRIVACY,HOBBIES,FAV,QULIFICATION,COMMUNITIES,GRPS,PAGES,NOTIFICATION,REQUESTS,TIPS,CITY,TAG)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    String stmnt=sb.toString();
    Connection con=prepareConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(stmnt);
    ps.setString(1,uname);

    File fl=new File("photo1");
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fl);
    ps.setBinaryStream(2,fis,(int)fl.length());

    File fl1=new File("music1");
    FileInputStream fis1=new FileInputStream(fl1);
    ps.setBinaryStream(3,fis1,(int)fl1.length());

    File fl2=new File("video1");
    FileInputStream fis2=new FileInputStream(fl2);
    ps.setBinaryStream(4,fis2,(int)fl2.length());

    File fl3=new File("shrs");
    FileInputStream fis3=new FileInputStream(fl3);
    ps.setBinaryStream(12,fis3,(int)fl3.length());

    File fl4=new File("updt");
    FileInputStream fis4=new FileInputStream(fl4);
    ps.setBinaryStream(15,fis4,(int)fl4.length());

    File fl5=new File(notes1);
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(fl5);
    ps.setCharacterStream(5,(int)fl5.length());

    File fl6=new File("messages1");
    FileReader fr1=new FileReader(fl6);
    ps.setCharacterStream(6,(int)fl6.length());

    ps.setString(7,"link");

    ps.setString(8,"frd");

    File fl7=new File("cmt");
    FileReader fr2=new FileReader(fl7);
    ps.setCharacterStream(9,(int)fl7.length());

    ps.setString(10,"lik");

    ps.setString(11,"ulik");

    File fl8=new File("qst");
    FileReader fr3=new FileReader(fl8);
    ps.setCharacterStream(13,(int)fl8.length());

    File fl9=new File("answ");
    FileReader fr4=new FileReader(fl9);
    ps.setCharacterStream(14,(int)fl9.length());

    ps.setString(16,"thms");

    File fl0=new File("wrd");
    FileReader fr5=new FileReader(fl0);
    ps.setCharacterStream(17,(int)fl0.length());

    ps.setString(18,"langs");

    ps.setString(19,"rlgn");

    ps.setString(20,"prvc");

    ps.setString(21,"hbc");

    ps.setString(22,"fvt");

    ps.setString(23,"qlf");

    ps.setString(24,"comm");

    ps.setString(25,"grp");

    ps.setString(26,"pgs");

    File fls=new File("ntfcn");
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(fls);
    ps.setCharacterStream(27,(int)fls.length());

    ps.setString(28,"rqst");

    File fls1=new File("tps");
    FileReader fr7=new FileReader(fls1);
    ps.setCharacterStream(29,(int)fls1.length());

    ps.setString(30,"cty");

    ps.setString(31,"tg");

    int i=executeUpdate();

    System.out.println("<<<<<<<Record Inserted Successfully>>>>>>> Count :"+i);

    con.close();
}
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    String uname="james";
    Blob photo1=img1.jpeg;
    Blob video1="Wildlife.wma";
    Blob music1="Lelepadi.mp3";
    Clob notes1="CreateTable.java";
    Clob messages1="CreateTable.java";
    String link="aaaaa";
    String frd="bbbb";
    Clob cmt="CreateTable.java";
    String lik="asadssfds";
    String ulik="zxzxxzcx";
    Blob shrs="img1.jpeg";
    Clob qst="CreateTable.java";
    Clob answ="CreateTable.java";
    Blob updt="img1.jpeg";
    String thms="bgfvdft";
    Clob wrd="CreateTable.java";
    String langs="erdgdfgf";
    String rlgn="bngfhgfh";
    String prvc="zxcsdw";
    String hbs="bgnbvc";
    String fvt="tgfhfghjfgh";
    String qlf="mklkopi";
    String comm="mbnfchgeshgw";
    String grp="bgyeadb";
    String pgs="hfhfj";
    Clob ntfcn="CreateTable.java";
    String rqst="ghfhgfh";
    Clob tps="CreateTable.java";
    String cty="jjkhgjghjk";
    String tg="qwewr";
    InsTable(uname,photo1,video1,music1,notes1,messages1,link,frd,cmt,lik,ulik,shrs,qst,answ,updt,thms,wrd,langs,rlgn,prvc,hbs,fvt,qlf,comm,grp,pgs,ntfcn,rqst,tps,cty,tg);
}
}
```

the above code produces following errors

```
 C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:45: error: no suitable   constructor found for File(Clob)
    File fl5=new File(notes1);
             ^
constructor File.File(URI) is not applicable
  (actual argument Clob cannot be converted to URI by method invocation conversion)
constructor File.File(File,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor File.File(String,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor File.File(String) is not applicable
  (actual argument Clob cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
constructor File.File(String,File) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor File.File(String,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
   C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:47: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(5,(int)fl5.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
 C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:51: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(6,(int)fl6.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:59: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(9,(int)fl7.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:67: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(13,(int)fl8.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:71: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(14,(int)fl9.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
   C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:77: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(17,(int)fl0.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:98: error: variable fr is already defined in method InsTable(String,Blob,Blob,Blob,Clob,Clob,String,String,Clob,String,String,Blob,Clob,Clob,Blob,String,Clob,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,Clob,String,Clob,String,String)
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(fls);
               ^
   C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:99: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(27,(int)fls.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
     C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:105: error: no suitable method found for setCharacterStream(int,int)
    ps.setCharacterStream(29,(int)fls1.length());
      ^
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(int,Reader,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
          C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
    int i=executeUpdate();
          ^
    symbol:   method executeUpdate()
      location: class InsertusrProf
       C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
    Blob photo1=img1.jpeg;
                ^
     symbol:   variable img1
         location: class InsertusrProf
         C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:121: error: incompatible types
    Blob video1="Wildlife.wma";
                ^
      required: Blob
        found:    String
       C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:122: error: incompatible types
    Blob music1="Lelepadi.mp3";
                ^
    required: Blob
     found:    String
      C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:123: error: incompatible types
    Clob notes1="CreateTable.java";
                ^
     required: Clob
     found:    String
  C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:124: error: incompatible types
    Clob messages1="CreateTable.java";
                   ^
       required: Clob
    found:    String
     C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:127: error: incompatible types
    Clob cmt="CreateTable.java";
             ^
    required: Clob
    found:    String
      C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:130: error: incompatible types
    Blob shrs="img1.jpeg";
              ^
        required: Blob
   found:    String
      C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:131: error: incompatible types
    Clob qst="CreateTable.java";
             ^
        required: Clob
        found:    String
       C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:132: error: incompatible types
    Clob answ="CreateTable.java";
              ^
      required: Clob
    found:    String
      C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:133: error: incompatible types
    Blob updt="img1.jpeg";
              ^
    required: Blob
       found:    String
   C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:135: error: incompatible types
    Clob wrd="CreateTable.java";
             ^
     required: Clob
    found:    String
     C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:145: error: incompatible types
    Clob ntfcn="CreateTable.java";
               ^
       required: Clob
      found:    String
     C:\Users\James P J\Documents\javaprog\skypark\InsertusrProf.java:147: error:  incompatible types
    Clob tps="CreateTable.java";
             ^
   required: Clob
    found:    String
24 errors

  Tool completed with exit code 1
```

I need to insert the information using parameters in the InsTable method

I tried with parameters without quotation like

```
   File fl=new File(photo1);
       FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fl);
    ps.setBinaryStream(2,fis,(int)fl.length());
```

but it was helpless

I searched solution for this problem online and I found similar type of code provided in the website :

```
  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/BlobandClobdatatype.htm
```

If any one know to solve this problem .Then Please help me

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter "notes1" is a `Clob`.  I don't know why you are attempting to create a `File` object with a `Clob` object.  Is "notes1" meant to be the filename?  Then it should be declared a `String`, not a `Clob`. Is it meant to be a `Clob` that contains the filename?  Then you will need to read the filename from the Clob's character stream, i.e.
`BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(notes1.getCharacterStream());`

Answer (score 0):

I count 30 "?" characters in your JDBC query string from your answer.  However, you only bind 24 of them.  Even if some of the values are intended to be `null`, you still need to bind them.

If you intend for those to be `null` in the database, then bind a `null` value with:

```
// Could be Types.CLOB, Types.INTEGER, or something else
ps.setNull(25, Types.VARCHAR);
```